# case: static binding? dynamic binding?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading, dynamic-binding, static-binding

I know that overloading uses static binding and overriding uses dynamic binding.
But what if they are mixed?
According to [this tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/what-is-static-and-dynamic-binding-in.html), to resolve method calls, static binding uses type information while dynamic binding uses actual Object information.

So, does static binding happens in the following example to determine which `sort()` method to invoke?

```
public class TestStaticAndDynamicBinding {
    
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Child();
        Collection c = new HashSet();

        p.sort(c);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Parent {
    
    public void sort(Collection c) {
        System.out.println("Parent#sort(Collection c) is invoked");
    }
    
    public void sort(HashSet c) {
        System.out.println("Parent#sort(HashSet c) is invoked");
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    
    public void sort(Collection c) {
        System.out.println("Child#sort(Collection c) is invoked");
    }
    
    public void sort(HashSet c) {
        System.out.println("Child#sort(HashSet c) is invoked");
    }
}
```

ps:
The output is :
`Child#sort(Collection c) is invoked`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two phases of binding here, as you suspected.

First, the static phase, that will choose to call `sort(Collection c)`. This is done in compile time, and since `c` is a reference of the `Collection` type, this method will be used, regardless of the runtime type (which is a `HashSet`).

Then, in runtime, since `p` actually contains a `Child` instance, it's method will be invoked, and you'll get `"Child#sort(Collection c) is invoked"`.

Answer (score 4):

during compile time, static binding determines method with which signature will be used (collection vs hashset). during execution, VM determines on which object the method will be invoked